# Don't show blank row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I bind data to a `DataGrid` it also shows a blank row. I don't want to show the blank row.

How can I show data in the `DataGrid` without showing a blank row?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AnnualInvoiceGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          x:Uid="AnnualInvoiceGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,6"
          MouseDoubleClick="PurchaseAnnualy_MouseDoubleClick">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set  `CanUserAddRows="False"` on your `DataGrid`. This will remove the empty row